# C file blocks.. how to know it?

Tags: c

I have a simple C file which is launched by a java application.

This script manage a physical sensor to detect distance. For every client i have more than one sensor. Every Object that access the C file run on a spirited thread. So basically when starting, the application creates one thread per sensor.

Now my problem is that I found that sometimes (don't know why...) one or more of threads stops working. They don't crash, they simply stops. I found in this moments that in the client process list the C file is in execution from long time (it usually last 2 seconds...). So I think the problem lies in the C executable. I don't know how to check where it blocks... I put an if condition on the time waiting for a signal, but it's not there..

This is the script

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int TRIG = atoi(argv[1]);
    int ECHO = atoi(argv[2]);

    wiringPiSetup();
    pinMode(TRIG, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ECHO, INPUT);

    int a;
    int totalDistance;
    int steps = 10;
    long travelTime;
    for (a = 0; a < steps; a = a + 1){
        digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);
        delay(100);
        // Send trig pulse
        digitalWrite(TRIG, HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(10);
        digitalWrite(TRIG, LOW);

        // Wait for echo start
        while (digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW);

        // Wait for echo end
        long startTime = micros();
        while (digitalRead(ECHO) == HIGH) {
            travelTime = micros() - startTime;
            if (travelTime > 25000) {
                travelTime = 25000;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("tempo: %d", travelTime);
        // Get distance in cm
        int distance = travelTime / 58;
        totalDistance = totalDistance + distance;
        delay(100);
    }
    int meanDistance = totalDistance / steps;
    printf("%d", meanDistance);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format, format, format...

Comment: how format can be responsible of the blocks? The actual script just prints ` printf( "%d", meanDistance);` (which is an int) because i import it in my java application

Comment: Format can be responsible for your code readability and the willingness to read it by people potentially able to hep you.

Comment: ah sorry, did not understood what you wanted to say, i will format it better

Comment: `while (digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW);' this looks like a potential infinite loop...

Comment: FYI, you can replace `int a; for (a = 0; a < steps; a = a + 1)` with simple `for (int a = 0; a < steps; a++)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Only if he uses a standard newer or equal to C99. Although it is pretty unlikly that he uses an older one ;)

Answer (score 0):

As ynimous suggested, you could try putting a timeout on the line

```
while (digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW);
```

Even if all it did was to print an error message, at least you'll be able to tell.  Something like this:

```
long lowStartTime = micros();
while (digitalRead(ECHO) == LOW) {
    if (micros() - startTime > 100000) { // or some reasonable value
        printf("error: echo timed out!");
        break; // and handle error appropriately
    }
}
```